# Set value of input control from input_group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set this input control using `$input_group.find('input');` but it is not getting set. Is this the correct way to use `find` and then set the value of the input control or is there anyway to do this?

```
            var $container = $('#gridrow-field-container');
            var template = $('#gridrow-template-input-group').get(0);

            $(item.MeetingPollingPartsValues).each((indexPartsValues, PartsValues) => {
                var $input_group = $(template.content.cloneNode(true));
                var inputControl = $input_group.find('input');
                inputControl.val(PartsValues.QuestionValue);

                console.log(inputControl);

                console.log($input_group);
                $container.append($input_group);
                $('input_group').val(PartsValues.QuestionValue);
            });


 <template id="gridrow-template-input-group">
         <div class='row mb-3' id='newrowItem_1'>
            <div class="input-group">
               <input type='text' id='fieldrowItem_1' name='name[]' class='form-control fieldrowItem mb-3' placeholder="Row 1" data-value="0" >
               <span  id='spanrowItem_1' class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;"  onclick="RemoveRow(this)"  >
                  <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
              </span>
         </div>
         </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: What is **$('input_group')**?

Comment: I created a test out of your code and the only thing I added was an empty div for **gridrow-field-container** and a test array and it worked for me.  I also removed the $("input_group") as it doesn't do anything. Here is a fiddle to see it working. I also removed the console.logs. https://jsfiddle.net/7u1r3hvd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added Bootstrap 5 dependencies and fixed the template.

You can clone the contents of the template with:

```js
const $inputGroup = $template.contents().clone();
```

```js
const $container = $('#gridrow-field-container');
const $template = $('#gridrow-template-input-group');

const RemoveRow = (span) => {
  $(span).closest('.row').remove();
}

const item = {
  MeetingPollingPartsValues: [
    { QuestionValue: 'One'   },
    { QuestionValue: 'Two'   },
    { QuestionValue: 'Three' }
  ]
};

$(item.MeetingPollingPartsValues).each((index, partValue) => {
  const $inputGroup = $template.contents().clone();
  const $inputControl = $inputGroup.find('input');
  $inputControl.val(partValue.QuestionValue);
  $inputControl.attr('placeholder', `Row ${index + 1}`);
  $inputControl.attr('data-value', partValue.QuestionValue);
  $container.append($inputGroup);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<template id="gridrow-template-input-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control"
          placeholder="Row x" data-value="0" >
      <div class="input-group-text" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(this)">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<div id="gridrow-field-container" class="container"></div>
```